# Tangent line at a specific point? Confused, please help

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

What is the equation of the tangent line at $x=8$, assuming that $f(8)=3$ and $f^{'}(8)= -\frac{4}{5}$

Comment: Do you know the meaning of the derivative at a point as the slope of the tangent line?

Comment: I'm struggling to be perfectly honest with you

Answer (score 1):

The tangent line to a function $f(x)$ at a point $a$ is a linear function (i.e., a line) $\ell(x)$ which matches the function value at $a$ and slope at $a$. That is, $\ell(a)=f(a)$ and $\ell'(a)=f'(a)$. This linear function must be given by the equation
$$\ell(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a).$$
Why is this the right formula? Well $\ell(x)$ is linear, so its slope is just the coefficient of $x$. We want that to be $f'(a)$, so we must have $\ell(x)=f'(a)x+C$ for some constant $C$. We could also write this as $\ell(x)=f'(a)(x-a)+D$ for some other constant $D$. Now we also want $\ell(a)=f(a)$. If we plug in $a$ we get $\ell(a)=f'(a)(a-a)+D=D$, so $D$ must be $f(a)$.

Now you can use the formula for the tangent line and the information you are given to determine the answer.

Comment: So I need to find the equation of the original line first? I just missed my most recent class and it feels like everyone's talking over my head right now. I'm so confused

Comment: You haven't been explicitly told what the function $f(x)$ is, and there is no way for you to determine what it might be. But you are asked to find the tangent line at the point $x=8$. That requires you to know two pieces of information: the value of $f(8)$ and the value of $f'(8)$. You have been given both of those pieces of information. Now you want the equation for the tangent line, which is a line going through the point $(8,f(8))$ and with slope $f'(8)$. My answer explains what the formula for that line is.

Comment: so is f(a) for this formula 8?

Comment: No, $a$ is $8$, because $a$ is the point at which you are taking the tangent line.

Comment: so would it look like this - 8+ (-4/5)(x - 8)?

Comment: excuse me, i meant to put 3's where the 8's are

Comment: I can't tell if you wrote "-" as a minus sign or a dash before the equation.

Comment: it was a dash, my mistake. so right now I have 3+(-4/5)(x-3)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A line is determined once you know a point on the line and you know the slope of the line. From the information given, what point is on the tangent line? And what is its slope?